# Loop for replace string by other one in different file

Tags: android, bash, for-loop, sed

I have two lists

**list1:**

```
A:1
B:3
C:1
D:5
```

**list2:**

```
1:blue
3:green
5:red
```

How can i do for have something like:

**Desired output(file3):**

```
A:blue
B:green
C:blue
D:red
```

And here is my unworking code ...

```
#!/system/bin/bash
list1=$(cat file1)
list2=$(cat file2)
for i in "$list1"; do
num_file1=$( echo $i | cut -d ":" -f 2)
string_file2=$(cat $list2 | grep "$num_file1" | cut -d ":" -f 2)
echo -e "$i" | sed "s/$num_file1/$string_file2/" > list3
done
```

I also tried
`sed 's/"$num_file1"/"$string_file2"/'` and many other but failed every times for what i want .. Where i am wrung with sed ??

**Ps: its on android ... and few command are misted ...**

Comment: Put `num_file1=...` and following line into the loop.

Comment: @PeterMmm i tried but still not working ...

Comment: sed : unmatched '/'

Answer (score 0):

Give this awk line a try:

```
awk -F':' 'NR==FNR{k[$1]=$2;next}{print $1 FS k[$1]}' f2 f1
```

I didn't test the code, but it should work.

**Note** this assumes that all idx in file1 we have corresponding entry in file2

Answer (score 0):

The `awk` solution is perfectly fine. Using lesser commands, you could say:

```
sort -t \: -k 2 list1 | join -t \: -1 2 - list2 | cut -d \: -f 2,3 | sort -t \:
```

Comment: I forget to said itd on android ... and there mist some command .. And `join` is part of the misted commands (as like paste and some few other..)

Comment: You should edit your original question, since that is a rather important omission.

Answer (score 0):

> Where i am wrung with sed ??

You were quite close, wrong only in three places.

- `for i in "$list1"; do` has to be `for i in $list1; do` without quotes, since you want to process the lines individually, not the whole `$list1` at once.
- `string_file2=$(cat $list2 | …)` has to be `string_file2=$(echo "$list2" | …)` with `echo` instead of `cat` (since you already read the `file2` into the variable `$list2`) and with quotes to preserve the line separation.
- The output redirection `> list3` has to be moved away from the `echo -e "$i" | sed …` line to the end of the `done` line, otherwise only the last output line would remain in `file3`.

---

Another approach to the problem would be to use an array for the colors, indexed by their number:

```
#!/bin/bash
eval rgb=($(sed 's/\(.*\):/[\1]=/' <file2)) # change 1:blue to [1]=blue etc.
while IFS=: read letter number
do  echo $letter:${rgb[$number]}            # change A:1 to A:blue etc.
done <file1 >file3
```